# "set editing-mode vi" vs "set -o vi" What is the difference?

Tags: bash, terminal, shell

On multiple forums I have come across adding `set -o vi` to my `.bashrc` file. Today I saw the option of adding `set editing-mode vi` to `.inputrc`.

I googled and both appear to do the same thing. Are there any key differences between the two?

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/760640/108618).

Answer (score 3):

Interactive Bash uses the [Readline library](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) to read command lines. Programs other than Bash can use the library as well. The library is designed to interactively read a command (or anything) from a user, with quite advanced line editing, key bindings, history and such.

`.inputrc` is the default file to customize Readline. Any program (including Bash) that uses Readline will be affected by what you put in the file (unless Readline uses another file; there are ways to customize). `set editing-mode vi` in `.inputrc` configures Readline directly.

`.bashrc` is the default file to customize Bash. It can be used to run anything and to configure Bash itself, including Readline *used by Bash*; but not Readline used by other programs. `set -o vi` enables vi mode in command line editing. In general [POSIX mandates `set -o vi`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set), but it does not force shells to use Readline. Only because Bash does use Readline, `set -o vi` in Bash has anything to do with Readline. Bash *implements* `set -o vi` by configuring Readline it uses. In Bash `set -o vi` is an indirect way to tell Readline used by Bash to set its `editing-mode` to `vi`.

The two methods you discovered give you the same result *in Bash*. For other programs using Readline, `.inputrc` matters and `.bashrc` doesn't. And any such program may or may not support its *own* rc file used to configure the program itself and possibly (indirectly) Readline used by it, like Bash does with `.bashrc`.

If Bash is about to use Readline and parse `.bashrc` then Readline will read `.inputrc` before `.bashrc` gets parsed. This means if there are conflicting settings for Readline in the two files, the setting(s) from `.bashrc` will reconfigure Readline last, so they will win.